# Conditional statements do not apply in Json Schema

Tags: json, validation, schema, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I would like to change the values acceptable to the Value B field according to the values of the Value A field in the following Json.

```
{"maximumList": [
{
  "ValueA": 232,
  "ValueB": ["aa"]
}]}
```

To do so, I obtained Schema using the Json Schema Generator and modified it to make it as follows.

```
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "maximumList": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "ValueA": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "ValueB": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "ValueA",
            "ValueB"
          ],
          "if":{
            "properties":{
               "ValueA" :{"const":232} 
            }
          },
          "then":{
             "ValueB":{
               "enum":["bbb"]
             }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "maximumList"
  ]
}
```

definitely set the value of the ValueB field to allow only "bbb", but even if "aaa" is entered in the value of the ValueB field, it passes the validation.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're using draft 4 of JSON Schema (identified by the `$schema` keyword value of `http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#`.

The `if`/`then`/`else` keywords are only supported in draft 7 and later.  If you change the `$schema` value to `http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#`, it should work for you.